# debug with svgalib program under linux

Tags: linux, gdb, librsvg

I have device which is running linux with svga library for user interface.  I tried to debug it by using GDB, but I got black screen when I initiated graphic by launching svga library.  Any body knows how I can make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up [remote debugging](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_131.html).

Then you can run the GDB on your workstation, and still use svgalib UI on the target device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am using NetBeans under ubuntu 10.04.  I can run GDBserver from my device, also get my GDB running on my workstation, but I can't catch the breaking point when program got launched. Do you know the reason?  or any suggestions for this kind debugging.  Thanks again for your additional response.

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be going wrong without any additional info. You may want to update your question with detailed logs of your interaction with GDB on host and gdbserver on target.